# Global state with redux somehow switches variables

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, use-state

I am very confused as to why this is happening as this has never happened with me before using redux. I am building a react native application and currently when I try to console log store.getStore() get the following output.

```
Object {
  "userState": Object {
    "currentUser": Object {
      "email": "test120@gmail.com",
      "username": "test13",
    },
    "listings": Array [],
  },
}
```

Now, when I dispatch my fetchUserListings() action, which should update the listings in the state the following happens.

```
Object {
  "userState": Object {
    "currentUser": Array [
      Object {
        "addressData": Object {
          "description": "2300 Yonge Street, Toronto, ON, Canada",
          "matched_substrings": Array [
            Object {
              "length": 3,
              "offset": 0,
            },
          ],
          "place_id": "ChIJx4IytjwzK4gRwIPk2mqEJow",
          "reference": "ChIJx4IytjwzK4gRwIPk2mqEJow",
          "structured_formatting": Object {
            "main_text": "2300 Yonge Street",
            "main_text_matched_substrings": Array [
              Object {
                "length": 3,
                "offset": 0,
              },
            ],
            "secondary_text": "Toronto, ON, Canada",
          },
          "terms": Array [
            Object {
              "offset": 0,
              "value": "2300",
            },
            Object {
              "offset": 5,
              "value": "Yonge Street",
            },
            Object {
              "offset": 19,
              "value": "Toronto",
            },
            Object {
              "offset": 28,
              "value": "ON",
            },
            Object {
              "offset": 32,
              "value": "Canada",
            },
          ],
          "types": Array [
            "street_address",
            "geocode",
          ],
        },
        "addressDescription": "2300 Yonge Street, Toronto, ON, Canada",
        "bath": "6",
        "benefits": Array [
          "Large Beds",
          "Nearby Bustop",
          "In-building gym",
        ],
        "urls": Array [
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/studenthousingfinder-11f55.appspot.com/o/listing%2FoHr0OMukEFguYxJborrvMAJQmre2%2F0.bd7cwka5gj?alt=media&token=81b3e06a-65a9-44a7-a32d-d328014058e7",
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/studenthousingfinder-11f55.appspot.com/o/listing%2FoHr0OMukEFguYxJborrvMAJQmre2%2F0.k78etqzypk?alt=media&token=e2622547-00f4-447b-8bea-799758734f0d",
        ],
      },
    ],
    "listings": Array [],
  },
}
```

Basically the API call is working and the state is updated, however somehow the data sent back is updating the currentUser in the state rather than the listings.

Here is my current reducer code:

```
import {USER_LISTINGS_STATE_CHANGE, USER_STATE_CHANGE} from '../constants';

const initialState = {
  currentUser: null,
  listings: [],
};

export const userReducer = (state = state || initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_STATE_CHANGE:
      return {
        listings: state.listings,
        currentUser: action.payload,
      };
    case USER_LISTINGS_STATE_CHANGE:
      return {
        currentUser: state.currentUser,
        listings: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and here are the 2 functions I use to make the API request

```
export function fetchUser() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    db.collection('users')
      .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists) {
          console.log('Yo');
          dispatch({type: USER_STATE_CHANGE, payload: snapshot.data()});
        } else {
          console.log('Does not exist');
        }
      });
  };
}

export function fetchUserListings() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    db.collection('posts')
      .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
      .collection('userListings')
      .orderBy('title', 'desc')
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        let listingArr = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          const id = doc.id;
          return {id, ...data};
        });
        dispatch({
          type: USER_LISTINGS_STATE_CHANGE,
          payload: listingArr,
        });
      });
  };
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I'm really lost as to why this is happening!

Comment: add console.log(action) above the switch in your reducer and check the payload what you receive for both cases

Comment: @KathirpandianK Did that. Somehow the type is USER_STATE_CHANGE and the payload is the correct payload which explains the switch in variables, but I have no idea why an incorrect type is being dispatched

Comment: Check your `constants` file. Maybe the value points to the same dispatch text.

Comment: Omg that was it I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake thank you so much!

Comment: Seems like you found your issue, voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers and good luck.

Comment: Generally please also be aware that you are writing a very old style of Redux. In modern Redux, you don't write switch..case reducers or ACTION_TYPE constants any more and write mutating logic in reducers. Check out the official Redux tutorial for a quick overview: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that your `users` collection in database might be having wrong entry.

Fact that brought me to this conclusion is that in your `fetchUserListings()` function, you're actually adding an extra field to json object i.e `id`.

Now, the `console.log` output doesn't contain this `id` field which could only mean that `fetchUserListings()` is not the one being called here.

You can try putting some try catch block and `console.log('fetchUser', snapshot.data())` & `console.log('fetchUserListings', snapshot.docs)` in respective functions to see which one is being called.